# Swift : Basic syntax

Tags: swift, syntax, enums, case

I am trying to make a calculator using Swift by MVC version. once I asked some one to help me and they gave me this piecse of code that i dont really understand then enum part and specially the cases nested in the enum.
In the other word what do we mean by

```
case UnaryOperation (String,Double -> Double)
case BinaryOperation(String,(Double,Double)-> Double)
```

the first part that one of the receiving arguments is a `String` make quite sense but the second part is making me quite confuse

```
class CalculatorBrain {

    enum Op{

        case Operand (Double)
        case UnaryOperation (String,Double -> Double)
        case BinaryOperation(String,(Double,Double)-> Double)

    }

    var opStack = [Op]()
    func pushOperand(Operand : Double){
        opStack.append(Op.operand(Operand))
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look into the free Swift book from Apple

Comment: BTW, the `append` is not right. You probably want something like: `func pushOperand(operand : Double){
        opStack.append(Op.Operand(operand))
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering these two:

```
case UnaryOperation (String, Double -> Double)
case BinaryOperation (String, (Double,Double) -> Double)
```

This just means that the `UnaryOperation` has two "associated values", one of which is a `String` and another is a closure (one that takes a `Double` as a parameter and returns a `Double`). The `BinaryOperation` is the same, except its closure takes two parameters, two `Double`.

Please refer to the [Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) (notably the "Associated Values" section) and [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapters from *The Swift Programming Language.*